# ASP.NET core Jwt authentication in gateway

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

I'm working on an application containing a gateway and several other projects.

Let's say the gateway project is called `Project.Gateway` and that my controllers are
divided into several other projects called `Project.XXX.API`.

My gateway use, among others things, YARP (Microsoft reverse-proxy) to redistribute the requests among the controllers.

I've been tasked to implement an authentication process with Json Web tokens.

I've also been expressly told not to use a Middleware, but to implement the JWT check with
`services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer(...);` in the `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method of my `Project.Gateway` startup file.

My issue is that this authentication seems to be triggered only when requesting a controller with the `[Authorize]` attribute, and the controllers are part of other projects. Thus putting the attribute on a controller ends with an error being thrown, as expected (Because no authentication schemes are declared in the `Project.XXX.API` projects)

So my question is :
Is there a way to trigger a JWT validation with `services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer(...);` without adding the `[Authorize]` attribute to the controllers, considering that my gateway and my controllers are in differents projects ? Can I add some kind of policy to this function not based on the controllers attributes ?

Comment: I think you might wish to set ``AddAuthorization( options => options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build(); ) `` this will mandate valid token.

Comment: @vpa1977 I tried to add this line in the ConfigureServices, and added the UseAuthorization() in the Configure method between the UseRouting() and the UseEndpoints() but it didn't change anything, the authentication is still not triggered

Comment: Did you call `RequireAuthorization` in `UseEndpoints(endpoints =>  endpoints.MapControllers()` ?  Otherwise, it would not apply policy at all. Its two parts - set a default policy (require authenticated user) and provide a default controller mapping that requires it.